# decorator 'NoneType' object is not callable

Tags: python, python-decorators

I'm trying to write a simple decorator that adds try/except to any function printing the error.

```
import random

def our_decorator(func):
    def function_wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        try:
            func(*args, **kwargs)
        except Exception as e:
                print(e)

@our_decorator
def test():    
    for a in range(100):
        if a - random.randint(0,1) == 0:
            print('success count: {}'.format(a))
            pass
        else:
            print('error count {}'.format(a))
            'a' + 1
```

I keep getting the error:

```
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I see no `return` statements anywhere...

Comment: I think you should return the wrapper  from you decorator

Comment: @our_decorator is a syntactic sugar. This is same as `test = our_decorator(test)` and calling `test()`. Since your decorator is returning `None`, `None()` will result in `TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable
`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The decorator needs to *return* the wrapper around the decorated function:

```
import random

def our_decorator(func):
    def function_wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        try:
            return func(*args, **kwargs)
        except Exception as e:
            print(e)
    return function_wrapper

@our_decorator
def test():    
    for a in range(100):
        if a - random.randint(0,1) == 0:
            print('success count: {}'.format(a))
            pass
        else:
            print('error count {}'.format(a))
            'a' + 1
```

As Daniel Roseman correctly noted in the comments: It wouldn't hurt returning the result of the function in the decorator. While it doesn't matter in this specific case, it is usually what you want.

Comment: Also it probably needs to return the result of calling `func` inside the wrapper.